# Why is mt-3 [mb-3] not applied to each row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows and want to add some space to the top and the buttom. So I added the attributes mt-3 and mb-3. But these attributes seems applied to the first row only.

How can I achieve apply them to every row?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3 mb-3" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is known as [**margin collapse**](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/):

> ... when the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero.

Essentially, the margin is applied to both elements, but the margins **overlap**.

To fix this, you have three options:

- `float: left`
- `position: absolute`
- `display: inline-block`

The easiest solution (in my opinion) is to simply apply `float: left` to the problematic elements:

```css
.mt-3, .mb-3 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <title>Web-UI-Automation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row mt-3 mb-3" style="background-color:white">
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-3 mb-3" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The rule is probably being overridden. Try increasing the [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), or loading your stylesheet *after* Bootstrap :)